# Details on specifying random parameters in 3-level HLM in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I am used to fitting 3-level HLM with HLM software, but now I am moving to `nlme` or `lme4` in `R`. Unfortunately, though, I am struggling a little bit with the proper specification/notation of the random parameters of the 2nd and the 3rd levels.

What I am trying to do is to estimate a 3-level linear model where some of the random effects are in the 2nd level, some are in the 3rd, but I do not know how to differentiate them in the "random" part of `lme()`. To make it clear, let me give you the specification equations:

```
Y = b0 + b1*X1 + b2*X2 + e

    b0 = a00 + a01*X3 + r0
    b1 = a10 + a11*X4 + r1
    b2 = a20 + r2

         a00 = c00
         a01 = c10 + u1
         a10 = c20 + u2
         a11 = c30
         a20 = c40
```

and the final model is

```
Y = c00 + c20*X1 + c40*X2 + c10*X3 + c30*X1*X4 + r0 + r1*X1 + r2*X2 + u2*X1 + u1*X3 + e
```

To estimate this model, so far I could only think of the following working codes:

```
lme(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X1:X4, random= ~ X1 + X2 + X3 | level3 / level2, data=mydataset)
lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X1:X4 + (1|level2) + (X1| level3/level2) + (X2|level2) + (1|level3) + (X3|level3), data=mydataset)
```

The `lme` seems to be somewhat wrong, as it estimates the random parameters of X1, X2 and X3 both in level 2 and in level 3, not the random compenents of X1 and x2 in level 2 and of X1 and X3 in level 3. In `lmer` I tried to do so, but I don't know if it is right to so in this way.

Please, could any of you give me some basic light here?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: It seems that the correct code is `lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X1:X4 + (1 + X1 + X2|level2) + (X1 + X3 - 1|level3), data=mydataset)`.

Comment: R.Astur - @Randel has suggested some fairly big changes to your model and code, most of which are good improvements. Assuming his edit gets approved (it may not), you should review the changes carefully and if they're not acceptable, you can roll them back - that is, you are able to undo them with a couple of clicks.